# Image sent over Wi-Fi Direct is corrupted

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial from the android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p) which explains how to send images over Wi-Fi direct. I essentially just copied what was there and instead of the image, it sends a corrupted jpeg of the same size. The data is sent fine and it is received on the other end, but it still produces a corrupted jpeg. The images which I am sending are definitely jpeg format as well. [This is what the image data stream looks like when it is received on the second device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11hmn.png)

Most of this was taken from the documentation so I don't see why it wouldn't work, but when I view the file on Android, it gets stuck loading and on Windows, it says that "File format not supported".

This is the code responsible for writing the image to the `OutputStream`.

```
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {

            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            ContentResolver cr = MainActivity.getContentResolver();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = cr.openInputStream(myUri);
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

This is the code responsible for receiving the bytes of the image files and creating a file from it.

```
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

                tempMsg = new String(buffer);

                if ((tempMsg = null)) {
                    ...
                } else if (!isASCII(tempMsg)) {
                    final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "mage.jpg");

                    File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                    if (!dirs.exists())
                        dirs.mkdirs();
                    f.createNewFile();

                    copyFile(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Comment: What `copyFile` method are you using?

Comment: The one that is used in the tutorial. It's on the WiFiP2PDemo https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/